# Doubles when i'm compiling sass-file

Tags: sass

When i'm compiling my sass-project by webpack, all doubles was removed, like:

```
border-top:   $caret-width-base dashed;
border-top:   $caret-width-base solid \9; // IE8
```

will be a

```
border-top:   $caret-width-base solid \9; // IE8
```

but i need to save all rules, because it's not a double, it's an ie-hack. What i can do for to solve this problem?

**UPD: Problem in `uglifyjsplugin`, but i couldn't find the necessary settings.**

Comment: Cannot reproduce, Sass does not remove styles arbitrarily: http://sassmeister.com/gist/dc597e4194b01d88040e

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Problem in `uglifyjsplugin`. But i can't find some setting that responds to this problem.